# ¿Cómo hacer que un card respete el tamaño de su imagen?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, css-grid-layout

Básicamente estoy haciendo como mi primer portafolio donde tiene varias secciones y entre ellas está la de `proyectos`. En esta parte tengo dos imágenes, que representan dos proyectos con una breve descripción de lo que hacen. Lo que trato de hacer con CSS Grid es un card image, que al pasar sobre él, aparezca un card que ocupa toda la imagen diciendo los lenguajes utilizados en este proyecto y que sobre esta imagen se encuentra la descripción del proyecto. Mis problema es el siguiente:

- no puedo hacer que el card solo sea en la imagen, debido a que también se extiende a todo el grid que contiene a la imagen y a la descripción.

He aquí un ejemplo de un portafolio que demuestra cómo es que quisiera que fuese de
[Brittany Chiang](https://brittanychiang.com/)

Agradeceria mucho a la person que me explique como solucionar este problema

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
*::before::after{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    color: #212121;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
}

.headerContainer{
    max-width: 1000px;
    height: 300px;
    padding: 0 100px;
    margin: 80px 0 450px;
}

.header-para{
    font-size: 25px;
}

.header-text{
    font-size: 65px;
}

.about-me{
    max-width: 1000px;
    height: 300px;
    padding: 0 100px;
    margin: 80px 0 450px;
    
}

.about-container{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: flex-start;
    
}

.text-container{
    max-width: 700px;   
    height: 300px;
}

.title{
    font-size: 40px;
}

.about-text{
    font-size: 18px;
}

.code-img{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.proyects{
    max-width: 1000px;
    height: 500px;
    padding: 0 100px;
    margin: 80px 0 450px;
}

/*PROBLEMA A PARTIR DE AQUI*/

.container-one{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12,1fr);
    gap: 10px;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 150px;
}

.card-img{
    grid-column: 1/10;
}

.proyects-img{
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
    border-radius: .8em;
    box-shadow: rgba(2, 12, 27, 0.7) 0px 10px 30px -10px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.container-one:hover .card-container{
    content: "";
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 3;
    background-color: rgba(2, 12, 27, .75);
    border-radius: .8em;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: all 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1) 0s;
    transition: 500ms;
}

.card-text{
    display: none;
}

.container-one:hover .card-text{    
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 4;
    margin: 15px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #212121;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}


.text-proyect{
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #212121;
    border-radius: .4em;
    grid-column: 7/-1;
    grid-row: 1/-1;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    align-items: center;
    box-shadow: rgba(2, 12, 27, 0.7) 0px 10px 30px -15px;

}

.proyect-title{
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 2px;
}

.proyects-text{
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="portfolio">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>My portfolio</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="headerContainer">
        <div class="header-data">
            <div class="text-container">
                <p class="header-para">Hi, My name is</p>
                <h1 class="header-text">Facundo</h1>
                <h1 class="header-text">And i'm a web dev.</h1>
                <p class="header-para">Hi,I'm Facundo Ferreria and i'm a beginner web developer who is learning and trying to do the best high-quality websites and applications.</p>
            </div>
            
            <img src="" alt="" class="photo">
        </div>
    </header>
    <section id="about" class="about-me">
        <h1 class="title">About Me</h1>
        <div class="about-container">
            <div class="text-container">
                <p class="about-text">Hi, My name is Facundo Ferreria, i'm a web developer who is now just a beginner and still learning the basics but with some new things. I'm just 16 years old boy from Argentina who got interested in web development and just wanna get started.</p>
                <p class="about-text">I started with "the programing world" last year but since i was studying i just started practicing in this vacations. I already have done just two projects because after the last one i thought that i should learn new thing, put them in practice and repeat that routine. My goal is to work as a freelancer and someday also develop my own personal proyects to sell</p>
                <p class="about-text">Here are all technologies i work with:</p>
                <ul class="skillsContainer">
                    <li class="about-text skillItem">HTML5</li>
                    <li class="about-text skillItem">CSS3</li>
                    <li class="about-text skillItem">Javascript (ES6)</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <img src="./img/web-development.png" alt="code-brackets" class="code-img">
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id="proyects" class="proyects">
        <h1 class="title">Some Things I've Built</h1>
        <div class="container-one">
            <div class="card-img">
                <img src="./img/todolist.png" alt="TO-DO-LIST" class="proyects-img">
                <div class="card-container">
                    <div class="contain-card-text">
                        <p class="card-text">HTML</p>
                        <p class="card-text">CSS</p>
                        <p class="card-text">JS</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="text-proyect">
                <h2 class="proyect-title">To Do List</h2>
                <p class="proyects-text">This is my first project and it's a TO-DO-LIST where you can put the tasks you have to  do and it will appear on the list that you can edit, delete, give them and order and more.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-two">
            <img src="./img/game.png" alt="ROCK-PAPER-SCISSORS-GAME" class="proyects-img">
            <div class="text-proyect">
                <h2 class="proyect-title">Rock, Paper and Scissors's Game</h2>
                <p class="proyects-text">The second proyect that i did was a game of rock, paper and scissors where you can play against the computer or against a player just like you.</p>
            </div>  
        </div> 
    </section>
    <section id="contact" class="contact">
        <h1 class="title">Contact Me</h1>
        <div class="inputs">
            <input type="text" class="input-one" placeholder="First Name">
            <input type="text" class="input-one" placeholder="Last Name">
            <input type="text" class="input-one" placeholder="E-mail">
            <input type="text" class="input-two">
        </div>
    </section>
    <footer>
        <div class="footerContainer">
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/facuferreria/" target="about:blank"><img src="./img/instagram.png" alt="ig" class="socials"></a>
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100006821357397" target="about:blank"><img src="./img/facebook.png" alt="fb" class="socials"></a>
            <a href="https://github.com/facuferreria" target="about:blank"><img src="./img/github.png" alt="github" class="socials"></a>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Esta pregunta debería cerrarse ya que el ejemplo no es muy reproducible tiene demasiados fallos, como algunas imágenes que no existen y además que hay enlaces de su twitter facebook y github.

Comment: y además no sé por qué el ejemplo está en inglés, cuando el sitio es en español.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando posicionas un elemento con `position: absolute`, él va a perder todo el espacio que ocuparía en el documento, no va a conocer quién es su padre cuando dices `width: 100%` o dónde ubicarse si dices `top: 0` o así, lo que va a hacer es buscar entre sus ancestros (hacia arriba en el DOM) quien es el primer elemento con `position: relative` o si no lo hay el documento HTML en sí.

El problema que mencionas, se debe a que en el caso de `<div class="card-container">` al contenedor con el texto de tecnologías tiene posición absoluta y su padre `<div class="card-img">` no tiene posición relativa, entonces cuando dices `width: 100%` se salta este elemento y toma el ancho de `<div class="container-one">` que contiene todo. Por esta razón tu card ocupa todo el espacio, incluyendo la descripción.

La solución, cambia la regla de la clase `.card-img` para que incluya `position: relative`.

```css
.card-img{
    grid-column: 1/10;
    position: relative;
}
```

Con todos los elementos en posición absoluta o relativa, tal vez debas agregar más cosas para mantener los objetos, sin que se superpongan.

Código completo:

```css
*::before::after{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    color: #212121;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
}

.headerContainer{
    max-width: 1000px;
    height: 300px;
    padding: 0 100px;
    margin: 80px 0 450px;
}

.header-para{
    font-size: 25px;
}

.header-text{
    font-size: 65px;
}

.about-me{
    max-width: 1000px;
    height: 300px;
    padding: 0 100px;
    margin: 80px 0 450px;
    
}

.about-container{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: flex-start;
    
}

.text-container{
    max-width: 700px;   
    height: 300px;
}

.title{
    font-size: 40px;
}

.about-text{
    font-size: 18px;
}

.code-img{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.proyects{
    max-width: 1000px;
    height: 500px;
    padding: 0 100px;
    margin: 80px 0 450px;
}

/*PROBLEMA A PARTIR DE AQUI*/

.container-one{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12,1fr);
    gap: 10px;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 150px;
}

.card-img{
    grid-column: 1/10;
    position: relative;
}

.proyects-img{
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
    border-radius: .8em;
    box-shadow: rgba(2, 12, 27, 0.7) 0px 10px 30px -10px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.container-one:hover .card-container{
    content: "";
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 3;
    background-color: rgba(2, 12, 27, .75);
    border-radius: .8em;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: all 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1) 0s;
    transition: 500ms;
}

.card-text{
    display: none;
}

.container-one:hover .card-text{    
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 4;
    margin: 15px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #212121;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}


.text-proyect{
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #212121;
    border-radius: .4em;
    grid-column: 7/-1;
    grid-row: 1/-1;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    align-items: center;
    box-shadow: rgba(2, 12, 27, 0.7) 0px 10px 30px -15px;

}

.proyect-title{
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 2px;
}

.proyects-text{
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="portfolio">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>My portfolio</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="headerContainer">
        <div class="header-data">
            <div class="text-container">
                <p class="header-para">Hi, My name is</p>
                <h1 class="header-text">Facundo</h1>
                <h1 class="header-text">And i'm a web dev.</h1>
                <p class="header-para">Hi,I'm Facundo Ferreria and i'm a beginner web developer who is learning and trying to do the best high-quality websites and applications.</p>
            </div>
            
            <img src="" alt="" class="photo">
        </div>
    </header>
    <section id="about" class="about-me">
        <h1 class="title">About Me</h1>
        <div class="about-container">
            <div class="text-container">
                <p class="about-text">Hi, My name is Facundo Ferreria, i'm a web developer who is now just a beginner and still learning the basics but with some new things. I'm just 16 years old boy from Argentina who got interested in web development and just wanna get started.</p>
                <p class="about-text">I started with "the programing world" last year but since i was studying i just started practicing in this vacations. I already have done just two projects because after the last one i thought that i should learn new thing, put them in practice and repeat that routine. My goal is to work as a freelancer and someday also develop my own personal proyects to sell</p>
                <p class="about-text">Here are all technologies i work with:</p>
                <ul class="skillsContainer">
                    <li class="about-text skillItem">HTML5</li>
                    <li class="about-text skillItem">CSS3</li>
                    <li class="about-text skillItem">Javascript (ES6)</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <img src="./img/web-development.png" alt="code-brackets" class="code-img">
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id="proyects" class="proyects">
        <h1 class="title">Some Things I've Built</h1>
        <div class="container-one">
            <div class="card-img">
                <img src="./img/todolist.png" alt="TO-DO-LIST" class="proyects-img">
                <div class="card-container">
                    <div class="contain-card-text">
                        <p class="card-text">HTML</p>
                        <p class="card-text">CSS</p>
                        <p class="card-text">JS</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="text-proyect">
                <h2 class="proyect-title">To Do List</h2>
                <p class="proyects-text">This is my first project and it's a TO-DO-LIST where you can put the tasks you have to  do and it will appear on the list that you can edit, delete, give them and order and more.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-two">
            <img src="./img/game.png" alt="ROCK-PAPER-SCISSORS-GAME" class="proyects-img">
            <div class="text-proyect">
                <h2 class="proyect-title">Rock, Paper and Scissors's Game</h2>
                <p class="proyects-text">The second proyect that i did was a game of rock, paper and scissors where you can play against the computer or against a player just like you.</p>
            </div>  
        </div> 
    </section>
    <section id="contact" class="contact">
        <h1 class="title">Contact Me</h1>
        <div class="inputs">
            <input type="text" class="input-one" placeholder="First Name">
            <input type="text" class="input-one" placeholder="Last Name">
            <input type="text" class="input-one" placeholder="E-mail">
            <input type="text" class="input-two">
        </div>
    </section>
    <footer>
        <div class="footerContainer">
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/facuferreria/" target="about:blank"><img src="./img/instagram.png" alt="ig" class="socials"></a>
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100006821357397" target="about:blank"><img src="./img/facebook.png" alt="fb" class="socials"></a>
            <a href="https://github.com/facuferreria" target="about:blank"><img src="./img/github.png" alt="github" class="socials"></a>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Bienvenido. Edité la respuesta copiando y pegando el snippet de la pregunta y cambié el detalle que mencionaste. Tanto en la pregunta como en la respuesta, al tocar el botón azul que dice Ejecutar, me salen las letras demasiado grande, no sé a qué de deberá, al final pienso que para solucionarlo no hay que hacer solo una línea de código sino que muchas más. Dejo una captura de pantalla: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAMsu.png

Comment: @ArtEze Correcto, para mejorar la UI hace falta mas de una linea de código, pero para resolver el problema que plantean en la pregunta pregunta basta con esa linea.